# Frame-rate drop while using custom python app in Deepstream SDK

Tags: python, gstreamer, picamera, nvidia-deepstream

***Using the deepstream_app_config_yoloV3.txt and TRT engine file fp16.engine, I got a FPS of 15 on yolov3-spp and a FPS of 30 on yolov3-tiny .***

My question is this:
Is there a way to recreate the fps I got running the  ***deepstream_app_config_yoloV3.txt*** onto  the ***python deepstream custom apps ?***

As I want to extract meta-data like detected object name and Bounding box coordinates.
If I can do this on the ***deepstream_app_config_yoloV3.txt app (not the custom-app.py script) I will be more than happy to ditch the python script***

My setup:

Jetson Nano  B01
Deep-stream 5.0
Jetpack 4.4
Camera: CSI Pi-camera V2

This is a modified  version of deepstream-app-test1 where I changed out the source  for the Pi-cam instead of video file.

While running the custom App I am getting about 5 fps due to the wired batching issue.
Is there anything I should modify to stop this batching and increase fps ?

I had added a parameter of 'fps =30/1' to see if it would make a difference but it didn't stop the batching

My code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
from common.is_aarch_64 import is_aarch64
from common.bus_call import bus_call

import pyds

PGIE_CLASS_ID_TOOTHBRUSH = 80
PGIE_CLASS_ID_HAIR_DRYER = 79
PGIE_CLASS_ID_TEDDY_BEAR = 78
PGIE_CLASS_ID_SCISSORS = 77
PGIE_CLASS_ID_VASE = 76
PGIE_CLASS_ID_CLOCK = 75
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BOOK = 74
PGIE_CLASS_ID_REFRIGERATOR = 73
PGIE_CLASS_ID_SINK = 72
PGIE_CLASS_ID_TOASTER = 71
PGIE_CLASS_ID_OVEN = 70
PGIE_CLASS_ID_MICROWAVE = 69
PGIE_CLASS_ID_CELL_PHONE = 68
PGIE_CLASS_ID_KEYBOARD = 67
PGIE_CLASS_ID_REMOTE = 66
PGIE_CLASS_ID_MOUSE = 65
PGIE_CLASS_ID_LAPTOP = 64
PGIE_CLASS_ID_TVMONITOR = 63
PGIE_CLASS_ID_TOILET = 62
PGIE_CLASS_ID_DININGTABLE= 61
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BED = 60
PGIE_CLASS_ID_POTTEDPLANT = 59
PGIE_CLASS_ID_SOFA = 58
PGIE_CLASS_ID_CHAIR = 57
PGIE_CLASS_ID_CAKE = 56
PGIE_CLASS_ID_DONUT = 55
PGIE_CLASS_ID_PIZZA = 54
PGIE_CLASS_ID_HOT_DOG = 53
PGIE_CLASS_ID_CARROT = 52
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BROCCOLI = 51
PGIE_CLASS_ID_ORANGE = 50
PGIE_CLASS_ID_SANDWICH = 49
PGIE_CLASS_ID_APPLE = 48
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BANANA = 47
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BOWL = 46
PGIE_CLASS_ID_SPOON = 45
PGIE_CLASS_ID_KNIFE = 44
PGIE_CLASS_ID_FORK = 43
PGIE_CLASS_ID_CUP = 42
PGIE_CLASS_ID_WINE_GLASS = 41
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BOTTLE = 40
PGIE_CLASS_ID_TENNIS_RACKET = 39
PGIE_CLASS_ID_SURFBOARD = 38
PGIE_CLASS_ID_SKATEBOARD = 37
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BASEBALL_GLOVE = 36
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BASEBALL_BAT = 35
PGIE_CLASS_ID_KITE = 34
PGIE_CLASS_ID_SPORTS_BALL = 33
PGIE_CLASS_ID_SNOWBOARD = 32
PGIE_CLASS_ID_SKIS = 31
PGIE_CLASS_ID_FRISBEE = 30
PGIE_CLASS_ID_SUITCASE = 29
PGIE_CLASS_ID_TIE = 28
PGIE_CLASS_ID_HANDBAG = 27
PGIE_CLASS_ID_UMBRELLA = 26
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BACKPACK = 25
PGIE_CLASS_ID_UMBRELLA = 24
PGIE_CLASS_ID_GIRAFFE = 23
PGIE_CLASS_ID_ZEBRA = 22
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BEAR = 21
PGIE_CLASS_ID_ELEPHANT = 20
PGIE_CLASS_ID_COW = 19
PGIE_CLASS_ID_SHEEP = 18
PGIE_CLASS_ID_HORSE = 17
PGIE_CLASS_ID_DOG = 16
PGIE_CLASS_ID_CAT = 15
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BIRD = 14
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BENCH = 13
PGIE_CLASS_ID_PARKING_METER = 12
PGIE_CLASS_ID_STOP_SIGN = 11
PGIE_CLASS_ID_FIRE_HYDRANT = 10
PGIE_CLASS_ID_TRAFFIC_LIGHT = 9
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BOAT = 8
PGIE_CLASS_ID_TRUCK = 7
PGIE_CLASS_ID_TRAIN = 6
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BUS = 5
PGIE_CLASS_ID_AEROPLANE = 4
PGIE_CLASS_ID_MOTORBIKE = 3
PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE = 2
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BICYCLE = 1
PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON = 0

pgie_classes_str= ["Toothbrush", "Hair dryer", "Teddy bear","Scissors","Vase", "Clock", "Book","Refrigerator", "Sink", "Toaster","Oven","Microwave", "Cell phone", "Keyboard","Remote", "Mouse", "Laptop","Tvmonitor","Toilet", "Diningtable", "Bed","Pottedplant", "Sofa", "Chair","Cake","Donut", "Pizza", "Hot dog","Carrot", "Broccli", "Orange","Sandwich","Apple", "Banana", "Bowl","Spoon", "Knife", "Fork","Cup","Wine Glass", "Bottle", "Tennis racket","Surfboard", "Skateboard", "Baseball glove","Baseball bat","Kite", "Sports ball", "Snowboard","Skis", "Frisbee", "Suitcase","Tie","Handbag", "Umbrella", "Backpack","Giraffe", "Zebra", "Bear","Elephant","Cow", "Sheep", "Horse","Dog", "Cat", "Bird","Bench","Parking meter", "Stop sign", "Fire hydrant","Traffic light", "Boat", "Truck","Train","Bus", "Areoplane", "Motorbike","Car", "Bicycle", "Person"]


def osd_sink_pad_buffer_probe(pad,info,u_data):
    frame_number=0
    #Intiallizing object counter with 0.
    obj_counter = {
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_TOOTHBRUSH:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_HAIR_DRYER:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_TEDDY_BEAR:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_SCISSORS:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_VASE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_CLOCK:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BOOK:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_REFRIGERATOR:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_SINK:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_TOASTER:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_OVEN:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_MICROWAVE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_CELL_PHONE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_KEYBOARD:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_REMOTE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_MOUSE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_LAPTOP:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_TVMONITOR:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_TOILET:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_DININGTABLE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BED:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_POTTEDPLANT:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_SOFA:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_CHAIR:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_CAKE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_DONUT:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_PIZZA:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_HOT_DOG:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_CARROT:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BROCCOLI:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_ORANGE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_SANDWICH:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_APPLE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BANANA:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BOWL:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_SPOON:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_KNIFE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_FORK:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_CUP:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_WINE_GLASS:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BOTTLE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_TENNIS_RACKET:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_SURFBOARD:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_SKATEBOARD:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BASEBALL_GLOVE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BASEBALL_BAT:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_KITE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_SPORTS_BALL:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_SNOWBOARD:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_SKIS:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_FRISBEE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_SUITCASE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_TIE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_HANDBAG:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_UMBRELLA:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BACKPACK:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_UMBRELLA:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_GIRAFFE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_ZEBRA:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BEAR:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_ELEPHANT:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_COW:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_SHEEP:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_HORSE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_DOG:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_CAT:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BIRD:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BENCH:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_PARKING_METER:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_STOP_SIGN:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_FIRE_HYDRANT:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_TRAFFIC_LIGHT:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BOAT:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_TRUCK:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_TRAIN:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BUS:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_AEROPLANE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_MOTORBIKE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BICYCLE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON:0
        }
    num_rects=0

    gst_buffer = info.get_buffer()
    if not gst_buffer:
        print("Unable to get GstBuffer ")
        return

    # Retrieve batch metadata from the gst_buffer
    # Note that pyds.gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta() expects the
    # C address of gst_buffer as input, which is obtained with hash(gst_buffer)
    batch_meta = pyds.gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta(hash(gst_buffer))
    l_frame = batch_meta.frame_meta_list
    while l_frame is not None:
        try:
            # Note that l_frame.data needs a cast to pyds.NvDsFrameMeta
            # The casting is done by pyds.glist_get_nvds_frame_meta()
            # The casting also keeps ownership of the underlying memory
            # in the C code, so the Python garbage collector will leave
            # it alone.
            #frame_meta = pyds.glist_get_nvds_frame_meta(l_frame.data)
            frame_meta = pyds.NvDsFrameMeta.cast(l_frame.data)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        frame_number=frame_meta.frame_num
        num_rects = frame_meta.num_obj_meta
        l_obj=frame_meta.obj_meta_list
        while l_obj is not None:
            try:
                # Casting l_obj.data to pyds.NvDsObjectMeta
                #obj_meta=pyds.glist_get_nvds_object_meta(l_obj.data)
                obj_meta=pyds.NvDsObjectMeta.cast(l_obj.data)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            obj_counter[obj_meta.class_id] += 1
            obj_meta.rect_params.border_color.set(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            try: 
                l_obj=l_obj.next
            except StopIteration:
                break

        # Acquiring a display meta object. The memory ownership remains in
        # the C code so downstream plugins can still access it. Otherwise
        # the garbage collector will claim it when this probe function exits.
        display_meta=pyds.nvds_acquire_display_meta_from_pool(batch_meta)
        display_meta.num_labels = 1
        py_nvosd_text_params = display_meta.text_params[0]
        # Setting display text to be shown on screen
        # Note that the pyds module allocates a buffer for the string, and the
        # memory will not be claimed by the garbage collector.
        # Reading the display_text field here will return the C address of the
        # allocated string. Use pyds.get_string() to get the string content.
        py_nvosd_text_params.display_text = "Frame Number={} Number of Objects={} Vehicle_count={} Person_count={}".format(frame_number, num_rects, obj_counter[PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE], obj_counter[PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON])

        # Now set the offsets where the string should appear
        py_nvosd_text_params.x_offset = 10
        py_nvosd_text_params.y_offset = 12

        # Font , font-color and font-size
        py_nvosd_text_params.font_params.font_name = "Serif"
        py_nvosd_text_params.font_params.font_size = 10
        # set(red, green, blue, alpha); set to White
        py_nvosd_text_params.font_params.font_color.set(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

        # Text background color
        py_nvosd_text_params.set_bg_clr = 1
        # set(red, green, blue, alpha); set to Black
        py_nvosd_text_params.text_bg_clr.set(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        # Using pyds.get_string() to get display_text as string
        print(pyds.get_string(py_nvosd_text_params.display_text))
        pyds.nvds_add_display_meta_to_frame(frame_meta, display_meta)
        try:
            l_frame=l_frame.next
        except StopIteration:
            break
            
    return Gst.PadProbeReturn.OK    


def main(args):
 # Standard GStreamer initialization
    GObject.threads_init()
    Gst.init(None)

    # Create gstreamer elements
    # Create Pipeline element that will form a connection of other elements
    print("Creating Pipeline \n ")
    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

    if not pipeline:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create Pipeline \n")

    # Source element for reading from the file
    print("Creating Source \n ")
    source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvarguscamerasrc", "src-elem")
    if not source:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create Source \n")

    # Converter to scale the image
    nvvidconv_src = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvvideoconvert", "convertor_src")
    if not nvvidconv_src:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create nvvidconv_src \n")

    # Caps for NVMM and resolution scaling
    caps_nvvidconv_src = Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "nvmm_caps")
    if not caps_nvvidconv_src:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create capsfilter \n")

    # Create nvstreammux instance to form batches from one or more sources.
    streammux = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvstreammux", "Stream-muxer")
    if not streammux:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create NvStreamMux \n")

    # Use nvinfer to run inferencing on decoder's output,
    # behaviour of inferencing is set through config file
    pgie = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvinfer", "primary-inference")
    if not pgie:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create pgie \n")

    # Use convertor to convert from NV12 to RGBA as required by nvosd
    nvvidconv = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvvideoconvert", "convertor")
    if not nvvidconv:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create nvvidconv \n")

    # Create OSD to draw on the converted RGBA buffer
    nvosd = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvdsosd", "onscreendisplay")

    if not nvosd:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create nvosd \n")

    # Finally render the osd output
    if is_aarch64():
        transform = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvegltransform", "nvegl-transform")

    print("Creating EGLSink \n")
    sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nveglglessink", "nvvideo-renderer")
    if not sink:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create egl sink \n")

    source.set_property('bufapi-version', True)
    caps_nvvidconv_src.set_property('caps', Gst.Caps.from_string('video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=720, height=480, framerate=30/1'))
    streammux.set_property('width', 720)
    streammux.set_property('height', 480)
    streammux.set_property('batch-size', 1)
    streammux.set_property('batched-push-timeout', 4000000)
    pgie.set_property('config-file-path', "config_infer_primary_yoloV3.txt")

    print("Adding elements to Pipeline \n")
    pipeline.add(source)
    pipeline.add(nvvidconv_src)
    pipeline.add(caps_nvvidconv_src)
    pipeline.add(streammux)
    pipeline.add(pgie)
    pipeline.add(nvvidconv)
    pipeline.add(nvosd)
    pipeline.add(sink)
    if is_aarch64():
        pipeline.add(transform)

    # we link the elements together
    # Csi camera -> -nvvidconv_src -> caps_nvvidconv_src ->
    # nvinfer (pgie)-> nvvidconv -> nvosd -> video-renderer
    print("Linking elements in the Pipeline \n")
    source.link(nvvidconv_src)
    nvvidconv_src.link(caps_nvvidconv_src)

    sinkpad = streammux.get_request_pad("sink_0")
    if not sinkpad:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to get the sink pad of streammux \n")
    srcpad = caps_nvvidconv_src.get_static_pad("src")
    if not srcpad:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to get source pad of decoder \n")
    srcpad.link(sinkpad)
    streammux.link(pgie)
    pgie.link(nvvidconv)
    nvvidconv.link(nvosd)
    if is_aarch64():
        nvosd.link(transform)
        transform.link(sink)
    else:
        nvosd.link(sink)

# create and event loop and feed gstreamer bus mesages 
    loop = GObject.MainLoop()

    bus = pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect ("message", bus_call, loop)

    # Lets add probe to get informed of the meta data generated, we add probe to
    # the sink pad of the osd element, since by that time, the buffer would have
    # had got all the metadata.
    osdsinkpad = nvosd.get_static_pad("sink")
    if not osdsinkpad:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to get sink pad of nvosd \n")
    osdsinkpad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BUFFER, osd_sink_pad_buffer_probe, 0)


    print("Starting pipeline \n")

    # start play back and listed to events
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    try:
      loop.run()
    except:
      pass

    # cleanup
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: `deepstream_app_config_yoloV3.txt` is being executed by `deepstream-app`, so you can modify/add the probe function (there are already two probe there, just check it - `osd` and `tracking_done_buf_prob`) there to extract bbox and other info. You can use the osd one as you're using here.